# Pascal's triangle code failing after certain row

Tags: java, recursion, pascals-triangle

```
import java.util.*;
public class PascalFinal
{
public static void main() 
{
    Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many rows of Pascal's triangle do you want to print: ");
    int row = f.nextInt();
    Pascal(row);

    showPascal(Pascal(row));
}

public static void showPascal(int[][] Pascal)
{
    for(int a = 0; a < Pascal.length; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < Pascal[a].length; b++)
        {
            System.out.print(Pascal[a][b] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static int[][] Pascal(int x)
{
    int[][] Pascal = new int[x][];
    int rowLength = 1;
    for(int a = 0; a < x; a++)
    {
        Pascal[a] = new int[rowLength];
        rowLength++;
    }



    for(int a = 0; a < Pascal.length; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < Pascal[a].length; b++)
        {
            int Piscal = a-b;

            Pascal[a][b] = Factorial(a)/Factorial(b)/Factorial(Piscal);
        }
    }

    return Pascal;
}

public static int Factorial(int n)
{

    if (n < 0) 
    {
        int x = -1;
        return x;
    }

    if (n == 0) 
    {
        int x = 1;
        return x;
    }
    else 
    {
        return (n * Factorial(n - 1));
    } 
}
```

When I run that code, it works perfectly fine for the first 13 lines, however it then starts putting in weird values for the rest of the rows. My first though was that it could be due to the values getting too big from the factorial method and the int datatype not being able to hold it but I am not sure. No clue why this is getting messed up. Please help.

Edit: I tried using the *long* datatype instead of int, but the same issue occurs once I get past 20 rows.

Comment: Yes, your first thought is almost certainly right; you're exceeding what fits into an `int`.  What do you want to do about it?  Switch to `long`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yep, just tried long but after 20 lines same things happens. Is there a datatype I can use that isn't going to be bounded by these values? I'm pretty sure this is occurring from the factorial method that I am using.

Comment: If you want 100% accuracy, you'll probably have to use BigInteger.

Comment: @PabloPisaco Yup, `BigInteger` is what you'd have to use to get arbitrarily large.

Comment: the number in the pascal's triangle are not so big after 20 rows. You should probably try to change how you are evaluating them.

Comment: I am evaluating by using a factorial method, so I think it is trying to calculate 21! which is outside the boundary of a long. I was think I could just add the previous two values of the row before, but I am not sure how I could do that @MarcoAltieri

Comment: @LouisWasserman , Is BigInteger a datatype? or is it a method that I can call?

Comment: @PabloPisaco yes it's a type found in `java.math`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Do not use the BigInteger... If this is an assignment, you should definitely try to implement it using a better algorithm

Comment: @MarcoAltieri I strongly suspect that if it's an assignment then the OP doesn't need to worry about overflow; I wouldn't expect this sort of thing to be tested on an intro assignment.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I do not think that a teacher will accept this type of solution. It is definitely not correct to evaluate super huge intermediate values when the result is a small integer.

Comment: This is a high school AP course so my teacher doesn't really care how I solve the problem. I would like to solve it in a simpler way if it is possible though. I know there are plenty of really short versions of this program, but I would rather not copy it into mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Pascal's triangle that you have to draw is the one designed [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/PascalTriangleProperties.shtml)
you do not need to evaluate any factorial.

Each row can be evaluated using the previous row with simple sums...

You can do it using an array. As a suggestion, start with the arrary: [0, 1, 0]
and remember that the next row can be evaluated doing a sum of the adjacent numbers of the previous row.

You need to loop over [0, 1, 0] and create [0,1,1,0] and then [0,1,2,1,0]

As you can see, the first is 0 and remains always 0, the next is the sum of the first two, and so on...

Comment: Yes, this was how I attempted to do it initially, but I was a bit lost on how to account for the end values since there are no values outside of the single 2-d array that I've created.

Comment: I have not tried, but I think that you can do everything "in place": using always the same array.

Comment: But when I print the array, don't I want to show just the values of Pascal triangle? Is there a way I can remove the zeros afterwards?

Comment: Just do not print them... if it is 0, print space

Comment: Okay, I'll give it go. Thanks for the help.